# Remove/ Undo Ignore Thread on deleted email

Tags: email, thunderbird

My thunderbird had a spaz out recently, and it seemed to do three things:

1. placed an "Ignore thread" on an email
2. deleted said email
3. created an archive folder in my inbox

This happened while I was attempting to write an email, and the draft became non-responsive without me knowing, and while I was typing, it seemed to take my input as command prompts/shortcut inputs? So now, I cannot see any new emails related to the one that was deleted.

For a while, there was a prompt to "Undo Ignore Thread", but pressing the button did nothing. I pressed it several times, and waited, to no avail. I ended up resetting Thunderbird, and the prompt disappeared.

I have since received new emails, and it says that I have 1 unread email, but I can't find it anywhere in my inbox, or any of the subfolders.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, luckily, in my case the message hadn't been deleted, only hidden.

There's an option to choose whether or not you want to see ignored threads. Select the folder (in my case, the Inbox), then go to `View > Threads > Ignore Threads`

This will show all threads you have chosen to ignore. To undo this, select the message you have placed the ignore on, then go to `Message > Ignore Thread`. Refresh the folder, and all following emails will appear.

Comment: Is there a way to show or sort _only_ Ignored Threads (so I can un-ignore them)?  It's useful when I've many emails in a folder, otherwise said threads get lost in the noise. I've not yet seen a way to show only or sort for Ignored Threads.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! :)

Comment: I'm still seeking a way to show or sort _only_ Ignored Threads. Anybody have a suggestion?  (@Ben?)

Comment: Answering my own question: in Thunderbird v91.6.0, selecting all messages (cmd-A in macOS) in a folder-message list, then `Message->Ignore_Thread` to "uncheck" the menucmd "toggle" value... IF it is checked. I _think_ that's the way to do it?  (Maybe after marking `Watch_Thread` first... maybe?)

Answer (score 0):

The problem I ran into with this Ben, is I have nearly a thousand messages in my Inbox, and when cat walked on my keyboard, had no idea which ones got ignored.  Toggling the `View > Threads > Ignore Threads` is a futile and frustrating effort since I can hardly tell what messages out of a thousand are now showing up that were hidden.

**An option to view only ignored threads would be helpful, Mozilla.**  Using TB 115 as of writing.

Absent that, I was fortunate to figure out a trick—led to by attempting [Johnny](https://superuser.com/users/98033)'s suggestion and may also answer his question—that was helpful in finding all the ignored threads and may help others as well:

1. "Select all" messages

   - The hint will be apparent when you see how many messages are selected, shown above the message list.  In my case, normally it showed "977 Messages" but when I selected all messages, that was appended and now showed "977 Messages, 969 Selected"
2. With all messages selected, activate the `View > Threads > Ignore Threads` option
3. The ignored threads are now shown, but unselected and easy to spot due to coloring of selected/unselected threads.

   - Now you can easily and quickly scroll through list of messages and see the ones that are ignored.

Best,